# Как программно указать xml-атрибуты для виджета?

Tags: java, android

Имеется [класс](https://gist.github.com/claudijo/0cf9f43705efadfeb852#file-typewriterview-java) . Нужно программно создать объект такого класса.
На входе он требует дать ему `Context` и `AttributeSet`.  `Context` - это, я так понимаю, просто `this`. А вот, в `AttributeSet`, походу, нужно поместить атрибуты будущего объекта. Я создал новый xml файл и поместил туда эти атрибуты.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <appname.TypewriterView
        android:id="@+id/tagline_typewriter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAlignment="textStart" />
</resources>
```

Русскоязычных материалов по теме не было, пришлось открыть документацию и откопать там вот такой простой пример.

```
XmlPullParser parser = getResources().getXml(????)
   AttributeSet  attrset = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
```

Проблема  в том, что я никогда раньше не обращался к самим файлам xml, только к их содержимому, и не знаю,  как указать путь к xml файлу, находящемуся в проекте. Или может я вообще не  в том направлении копаю, пытаясь создать объект TypewriterView?

Comment: А вы этот класс просто скопировали в свой проект? Если да, то просто допишите конструктор только с контекстом, без атрибутов, как в дефолтных View

Comment: Ну, я его совсем малость изменял под себя, убрав  private с некоторых переменных. Только не говорите, что проблема в этом :D TypewriterView (Context, AttributeSet) in TypewriterView cannot be applied to (classname) . Сейчас пытаюсь сделать так, как Вы сказали в постскриптуме ответа.

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо, что помогли с `getXml`. Всё работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все xml-атрибуты имеют связанные методы-сеттеры, реализуемые [классом `View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) и его наследниками (в вашем случае [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), [`EditText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)). При програмном создании виджета вы создаете объект этого виджета через дефолтный конструктор, а затем через эти сеттеры назначаете ему необходимые атрибуты. Геометрические размеры на экране задаются через метод `setLayoutParams()`.

К примеру, назначаем [`padding`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:padding) (это атрибут класса `View`, внизу описания XML-атрибута связанный метод для програмной установки значения):

```
TypewriterView typeView = new TypewriterView(this);
typeView.setPaddingRelative(8,8,8,8);
```

назначаем [`textSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textSize) (это атрибут класса `TextView`):

```
typeView.setTextSize(40);
```

Значение указывается в пикселях, поэтому потребуется еще метод перерасчета из единиц *sp* в пиксели.

геометрические параметры:

```
typeView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Все атрибуты, которые реализует класс (а в описании атрибутов, связанные с ними методы) указаны в документации. Например, для [класса `View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#lattrs).

узнать [подробнее](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/layout.php#code)

PS: так же возможно наверное и парсить из ресурсов, как в вашем вопросе (сам я этого не делал). метод `getXml()` принимает параметром ID ресурса с xml-кодом, вида *R.xml.myAttr* - `getXml(R.xml.myAttr)`, где *myAttr* - имя файла, содержащего xml-разметку. Сам файл должен быть помещен [в папку *res/xml/*](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/resources.php#xml)

Comment: `При програмном создании виджета вы создаете объект этого виджета через дефолтный конструктор,` Можно пример?  `view.findViewById(R.id.typewriter);` Здесь Вы обращаетесь к typewriter, созданному в layout, насколько я понимаю, мне же нужно следующее: http://imgur.com/a/tqsMq

Comment: я исправил. Немного отвлекся.

Comment: @FullyRetarded добавил немного по, собственно, вашему вопросу, что вставить в метод `getXml()`, может поможет, но я такой способ в первый раз вижу и не могу сказать о его работоспособности ничего.

Comment: сами атрибуты мне пока не нужны. Я вернусь к вашим примерам работы с атрибутами, но чуть попозже, если смогу программно создать TypeWriter. А про атрибуты я заговорил потому, что `TypewriterView typeView = new TypewriterView(this);` не будет компилироваться потому, что TypeWriter  на входе требует набор атрибутов: `TypewriterView (Context, AttributeSet) in TypewriterView cannot be applied to (classname)`